# Chrome extension tooltip over text(one word)

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'd like to implement a tooltip dictionary chrome extension. When the user hover the mouse over a chunk or a word in text, It should show the block selection or change its background color and show the tooltip under the word.

How can I implement it?

I just did similar thing with `background` like this:

core.js

```
// Unique ID for the className.
var MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME = 'crx_mouse_visited';

// Previous dom, that we want to track, so we can remove the previous styling.
var prevDOM = null;

// Mouse listener for any move event on the current document.
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function (e) {
  var srcElement = e.srcElement;

  // Lets check if our underlying element is a DIV.
  if (srcElement.nodeName == 'DIV' || srcElement.nodeName == 'SPAN') {

    // For NPE checking, we check safely. We need to remove the class name
    // Since we will be styling the new one after.
    if (prevDOM != null) {
      prevDOM.classList.remove(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);
    }

    // Add a visited class name to the element. So we can style it.
    srcElement.classList.add(MOUSE_VISITED_CLASSNAME);

    // The current element is now the previous. So we can remove the class
    // during the next iteration.
    prevDOM = srcElement;
  }
}, false);
```

core.css

```
.crx_mouse_visited {
  background-color: #bcd5eb !important;
  outline: 1px solid #5166bb !important;
}
```

Comment: There's no special API for this so you'll have to use the standard DOM methods/libraries in a [content script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch).

Comment: Yes, But I don't know how to implement it. I just implemented `div` and `span` detection and I can get the text. And after that, I have no idea how to do the things I am thinking. And is there any good tool for the development? I am using Atom and It doesn't have any auto-completion.

Comment: It's standard DOM + CSS. You can inspect the source code of other extensions with similar functionality by debugging their content scripts in devtools or just read their code.